# Windows Phone 7: Push notifications work on emulator, not on device

Tags: windows-phone-7, push-notification, mpns

I'm having a strange issue with push notifications.  When running on the emulator, I open or create the communication channel with no issues, and my ChannelUriUpdated method gets called promptly.  Server pushes notifications, I receive them...bueno!

But on the device, a funny thing happens.  The open/create calls seem to work just fine...no errors/exceptions thrown...but the ChannelUriUpdated callback never gets hit, and therefore I never get my URL to use for push.

My device is purely for development, so I don't have a SIM card in it, but it does have a net connection via wi-fi and also via the tether of course.  So I can't imagine that's the reason it's not working.

I would expect an exception or error condition, but nothing seems to be amiss.

Have any of you guys seen this kind of behavior?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be related to the phone firmware.  I was running the default (shipped) version of the OS on my HTC device.  I believe the version was 7004.